# Constant Temperature Cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, physical-chemistry

In my thermodynamics textbook there is part of a question that seems to be a contradiction.

...Superheated refrigerant R-134a at 20 C, 0.5 MPa is cooled in a piston/cylinder arrangement at constant temperature to a final two-phase state with quality of 50%...

Why would it say it is "cooled ... at a constant temperature" ? I understand there is a change in volume and pressure but if the temperature is constant how can it be cooled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "cooling" the book means "subtracting heat/energy". Even if usually adding and subtracting energy at constant pressure changes the temperature of a substance, this is not true at a phase transition point where you can add and subtract energy at fixed temperature and pressure by varying the amount of the two phases, and thus usually volume.

This is for example what happens when you cool water to make ice, once you reach 0° C both liquid water and ice would be stable, but they differ in the amount of internal energy. In order to turn the water into ice you need to subtract more heat/energy and both temperature and pressure may stay constant. Volume usually changes and the phase transition is [the flat line in the temperature/volume diagram at constant pressure](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Thermodynamics/Applications#One_Component_Systems).